# Delphi - Sorting real numbers in high, low, high, low order

Tags: delphi, sorting, pascal

Say I have the data 
1,2,3,4,5,6

I want to sort this data so that it outputs
6 1 5 2 4 3

This way, numbers are matched so that low numbers pair with high numbers

Would i use a merge sort to sort it in numerical order, then split the list and match them according to this conditions?

I'm trying to sort real number data in a string grid which is read from a data file; I have a working program that sorts these data in numerical order but I'm not sure how to code it so that it sorts in terms of high,low,high,low

This is the code for my grid sorting

```
procedure TForm1.SortGrid(Grid: TStringGrid; const SortCol: Integer;
//sorting the string grid
  const datatype: Integer; const ascending: boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
  tempgrid: TStringGrid;
  list: array of Integer;
begin
  tempgrid := TStringGrid.create(self);
  with tempgrid do
  begin
    rowcount := Grid.rowcount;
    ColCount := Grid.ColCount;
    fixedrows := Grid.fixedrows;
  end;
  with Grid do
  begin
    setlength(list, rowcount - fixedrows);
    for i := fixedrows to rowcount - 1 do
    begin
      list[i - fixedrows] := i;
      tempgrid.rows[i].assign(Grid.rows[i]);
end;
   Mergesort(Grid, list, SortCol + 1, datatype, ascending);


      for i := 0 to rowcount - fixedrows - 1 do
      begin
    rows[i + fixedrows].assign(tempgrid.rows[list[i]])
      end;
      row := fixedrows;
    end;
    tempgrid.free;
    setlength(list, 0);
  end;
```

Comment: If you want to sort numbers in high-low-high-low order shouldn't you get 6 1 5 2 4 3 from initial data?

Comment: i only wrote that really quickly with no thought  but yeah in that order

Comment: I rolled your question back. The original question was fine and has been answered.

Comment: How to handle the numbers with duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

First, sort the numbers in descending order by using any algorithm you want (I used bubble sort in example)

Then, if you have n elements in array:

- set a counter going from 1 to (n div 2)
- take last element and store it in temporary variable (**tmp**)
- shift all elements by one place to the right, starting from **(counter - 1) * 2 + 1**. This would overwrite last element, but you have it stored in **tmp** var
- set **array[(counter - 1) * 2 + 1]** element to **tmp**
- end counter

This way you would effectively take last element from array and insert it at 1, 3, 5... position, until you insert last half of array elements.

*Sample code:*

```
procedure Sort(var AArray: array of Double);
var
  C1, C2: Integer;
  tmp   : Double;
  pivot : Integer;
begin
  for C1 := Low(AArray) to High(AArray) - 1 do
    for C2 := C1 + 1 to High(AArray) do
      if AArray[C1] < AArray[C2] then
      begin
        tmp := AArray[C1];
        AArray[C1] := AArray[C2];
        AArray[C2] := tmp;
      end;

  pivot := Length(AArray) div 2;
  for C1 := 1 to pivot do
  begin
    tmp := AArray[High(AArray)];
    for C2 := High(AArray) downto (C1 - 1) * 2 + 1 do
      AArray[C2] := AArray[C2 - 1];
    AArray[(C1 - 1) * 2 + 1] := tmp;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How would i do this for records in a string grid

Comment: You should populate dynamic array with grid data and pass it to Sort() function, then clear grid and repopulate it with data that Sort() returned.

Comment: sorry for the trouble, i have no clue how to do that

Comment: Are you storing the data in a string grid? That's usually a bad idea.

Comment: I think he has bigger problems at the moment than the way he stores the data :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah the stringgrid reads the records from a dat. file

Comment: @Nathan The question you asked has been answered. The fact that you are a novice and don't know how to code it up is your problem and unrelated to the question you asked.

Comment: @Marko I'm not sure. If he stored the data in a dedicated data structure then he could sort that and then apply hi/lo when populating gui control. Personally this screams list view virtual mode to me.

Comment: @Marko Also I really don't like your solution. Lots of extraneous copying. I'd add an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: @David it all depends on what he needs, but I agree that in-array operations are not needed if he only wants to populate grid with hi-lo data, and that your code is better for that case.

Answer (score 2):

From sample data you provided above, I am assuming that the input array is presorted.

[Note that I don't have a compiler at hand, so you'll have to run it and see that it works --minor fiddling might be needed.]

```
procedure SerratedSort(var AArray: array of Double);
var
  Length1: Integer;
  Index1: Integer;
  Temp1: Double;
begin
  Length1 := Length(AArray);
  Index1 := 0;
  while Index1 < Length1 do begin
    Temp1 := AArray[Length1 - 1];
    System.Move(AArray[Index1], AArray[Index1 + 1], (Length1 - Index1 + 1) * SizeOf(Double));
    AArray[Index1] := Temp1;
    Index1 := Index1 + 2;
  end;
end;
```

Here is how it (should) work(s) step-by-step

**Input AArray: 123456**

- Index1: 0

> Temp1 := 6
>
> System.Move: 112345
>
> AArray: 612345

- Index1: 2

> Temp1 := 5
>
> System.Move: 612234
>
> AArray: 615234

- Index1: 4

> Temp1 := 4
>
> System.Move: 615233
>
> AArray: 615243

**Output AArray: 615243**

---

For a record structure, such as, TPerson, it would be like this:

```
procedure SerratedSort(var A: array of TPerson);
var
  s: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  t: TPerson;
begin
  s := Length(A);
  i := 0;
  while i < s do begin
    t := A[s - 1];
    System.Move(A[i], A[i + 1], (s - i + 1) * SizeOf(TPerson));
    A[i] := t;
    i := i + 2;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: First, IMO it is sloppy programming to use the Grid itself to sort the data. You should use an intermediate array. Secondly, please do not keep changing the question.

Comment: Im not going for efficiency, this is the only method i know how to do as i am not experienced with programming

Comment: Nobody is talking about efficiency here.

Comment: Inexperience in programming isn't an excuse for the lack of aptitude when it comes to defining the problem. Your first attempt was correct as it asked for a snippet to algorithmically solve a generalizable problem. Now you've turned it into a "write my program for me". Please refrain from doing that. You are given the solution. Adapt it to your TPerson record structure --or use the indices in that TPerson Array.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the data in ascending order. Then pick out the values using the following indices: 0, n-1, 1, n-2, ....

In pseudo code the algorithm looks like this:

```
Sort;
lo := 0;
hi := n-1;
while lo<=hi do
begin
  yield lo;
  inc(lo);
  if lo>hi then break;
  yield hi;
  dec(hi);
end;
```

Comment: i forgot to mention my knowledge in programming is very minimal so i have no clue in how to do that

Comment: @Nathan: Then you need someone to write the complete program for you.

Answer (score 1):

Example program demonstrating the already above given solutions:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

const
  Count = 12;
type
  TValues = array[0..Count - 1] of Double;
const
  Input: TValues = (1,2,4,9,13,14,15,23,60,100,101,102);
var
  I: Integer;
  Output: TValues;

procedure ShowValues(Caption: String; Values: TValues);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Write(Caption);
  for I := 0 to Count - 2 do
    Write(Round(Values[I]), ', ');
  WriteLn(Round(Values[Count - 1]));
end;

begin
  if Odd(Count) then
    WriteLn('Cannot compute an odd number of input values')
  else
  begin
    WriteLn('Program assumes sorted input!');
    ShowValues('Input:  ', Input);
    for I := 0 to (Count div 2) - 1 do
    begin
      Output[2 * I] := Input[I];
      Output[2 * I + 1] := Input[Count - 1 - I];
    end;
    ShowValues('Output: ', Output);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: It is simple to cater for arrays with odd length